# Import a custom class from another subfolder JAVA

Tags: java, class, import

I have one class in the following directory :

> examples.AgentDerivation;

And another one in

> examples.AgentClient;

The thing is, the first one needs the second one but I get the "Symbol error" when I try to compile.

Is there any way to do an import ? I want to do something like import ../AgentClient; but I can't find the good syntax for it.

Please help !

Comment: Are you using packages?

Comment: yes, the fist one is in the package examples.AgentDerivation; and the second in examples.AgentClient;

Comment: `import examples.AgentClient;` on your agentDerivation **class**

Comment: it's not working this way, the compiler doesn't find "examples.agentClient".

It's looking inside AgentDerivation for examples.AgentClient hence the error

Comment: If you attach more information i could help you, please provide minimal code so i can reproduce the error.

Comment: The error is easily reproducible, the code is too long (I get character restriction)

For example you have package examples.b where you create a random class B :
in this one you'll need to instanciate an object from a class A that is found in the package examples.a 

If you try to do so, you'll get an error because B doesn't recognize A. 

I'm looking for a way to get the .class file of B to check into A folder.

I hope it's clearer right now. And thanks for taking time to read this :)

Comment: Maybe you should read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Answer (score 0):

From package `something.b` you can import a `something.a` class by `import container.random.A.*;`

Check this example:

### Configuration:

[image: PackageConfig]

### RandomA:

```
package container.random.A;

public class RandomA
{
    private int randomAID;

    public RandomA()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @return the randomAID
     */
    public int getRandomAID ( )
    {
        return randomAID;
    }

    /**
     * @param randomAID the randomAID to set
     */
    public void setRandomAID ( int randomAID )
    {
        this.randomAID = randomAID;
    }




}
```

### RandomB:

```
package container.random.B;

import container.random.A.*;

public class RandomB
{
    private int RandomBID;
    private RandomA myForeignRandom;

    public RandomB(RandomA myForeignRandom)
    {
        this.setMyForeignRandom ( myForeignRandom );
    }

    /**
     * @return the randomBID
     */
    public int getRandomBID ( )
    {
        return RandomBID;
    }

    /**
     * @param randomBID the randomBID to set
     */
    public void setRandomBID ( int randomBID )
    {
        RandomBID = randomBID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the myForeignRandom
     */
    public RandomA getMyForeignRandom ( )
    {
        return myForeignRandom;
    }

    /**
     * @param myForeignRandom the myForeignRandom to set
     */
    public void setMyForeignRandom ( RandomA myForeignRandom )
    {
        this.myForeignRandom = myForeignRandom;
    }

}
```

### Test:

```
package container.random.B;

import container.random.A.RandomA;

public class test
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        RandomA randomA = new RandomA ( );
        randomA.setRandomAID ( 1 );

        RandomB randomB = new RandomB ( randomA );
        System.out.println ( randomB.getMyForeignRandom ( ).getRandomAID ( ) );

        randomA.setRandomAID ( 2 );
        System.out.println ( randomB.getMyForeignRandom ( ).getRandomAID ( ) );

    }

}
```

### Output:

> 1
>
> 2

The output are the IDs of A class from B.

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work, so I just put them in the same package. Now it's all good, it's for a school assignment I think that should do.

Thank's a lot for your answers !!